# ASPNET Core replacement for [Session] =

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc

We are migrating from ASPNET MVC5 to ASPNET Core meaning we need to refactor some code.

We were using Session = model to store the model in the session, then retrieving it from another Controller.

We understand this option has been discontinued in Core.

We have attempted to use:
`HttpContext.Session.SetString("Data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));`

However, when Deserialising by using:

```
var json = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Data");
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchListViewModel>(json);
```

The resulting model does not come back the same - it is one long string rather than a structured list (which is was before Serialising).

Is there a better way to achieve passing a model from one controller to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure `Session` in your project, you need to do the following:

In your `Startup.cs`, under the `Configure` method, add this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseSession();
}
```

And then under the `ConfigureServices` method, add this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //Added for session state
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

  services.AddSession(options =>
  {
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);               
  });
}
```

Create a model class of your object type (whatever you want to store). I am giving a simple example:

```
public class SearchListViewModel
{
    public int SearchID{ get; set; }
    public string SearchName{ get; set; }
    //so on
}
```

Then create a `SessionExtension` helper to set and retrieve your complex object as JSON:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
  public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
  {
     session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
  }

  public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
  {
     var value = session.GetString(key);
     return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
  }
}
```

Then finally set the complex object in your session as:

```
var search= new SearchListViewModel();
search.SearchID= 1;
search.SearchName= "Test";   
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("SearchListViewModel", search);
```

To retrieve your complex object in your session:

```
var searhDetails = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<SearchListViewModel>("SearchListViewModel");
int searchID= SearchListViewModel.SearchID;
string searchName= SearchListViewModel.SearchName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can still use session if you need. You just need to config it in startup

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSession();
             
            ....another your code
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseSession();

            ... another your code

        }
```